# When I have 2 tableviews in one view controller, cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called for second UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIView that gets loaded from a xib file. It has two UITableView's. I wanted to display different data in each UITableView and decided not to use indexPath.section.

So with that in mind - I wrote up my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *UsernameCellIdentifier = @"UsernameCell";
    static NSString *PasswordCellIdentifier = @"PasswordCell";
    static NSString *mailListTableViewCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (tableView == self.maillistTableview ){

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.maillistTableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mailListTableViewCellIdentifier];
        if (!cell){

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:mailListTableViewCellIdentifier];
        }


        cell.textLabel.text = @"Cells";
        return cell;
    }


    if (tableView == self.tableView){

        if(indexPath.row == 0) {

        self.usernameCell = (BBUsernameTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:UsernameCellIdentifier];

        if(!self.usernameCell) {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:UsernameCellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];

        return self.usernameCell;
    }

    return nil; 
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it is only called twice for the first table view: `self.tableView`

I added an NSLog inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath to see which tableView it was looking at and it never "checks" self.maillistTableView

I have connected the delegates for that UITableView to the file owner.

Interestingly in `numberOfRowsInSection` it is working for `self.maillistTableView`.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: is it "`self.maillistTableView`" or "`self.maillistTableview`"? Case sensitivity matters. Your source snippet says one thing and your "It is working for…" says another.

Comment: what numberOfRowsInSection  returns for elf.maillistTableView

Comment: Sorry the that's just a copy and past error in self.maillistTableView. Both spelt same in code. The count of the array is returned correctly to the table view

Comment: @Akhilrajtr - Seems you were onto something. My array count was actually zero. I did not check it properly and this is why it wasn't calling cellForRowAtIndexPath - as there were no cells to display. Put this comet as answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `numberOfRowsInSection` is working, check it's return count. If the datasource array count is zero,  then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not work.

Comment: As added in other comments - this was my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe `self.maillistTableView` not call reloadData

Comment: Calling [self.maillistTavbleview reloadData] after the view has loaded, seems to work. Very odd it doesn't do it on first load of the view?